# ¿Por qué mi impresión sale Null?

Tags: java, array, string, eclipse, null

soy estudiante, estoy intentando **imprimir el nombre del departamento** con más ausencias ingresado, pero en la impresión me **aparece como null** y no sé que estoy haciendo mal. Aquí les muestro algo del código.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AusenciasMes {
    
    private static int departs=2;
    private static int mes=2;
    private int ausencias[][];
    private String nombre[];
    Scanner datos = new Scanner(System.in);
    
//--FUNCION FIJAR VALORES
    public void FijarValor(int ausencias[][], String nombre[]){
        this.ausencias= new int[departs][mes];
        this.nombre= new String[50];
        for(int i=0;i<departs;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<mes;j++){
                this.ausencias[i][j]=ausencias[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Esta funcion debería retornarme (según yo xd) el nombre del que tuvo más ausencias.

```
//--FUNCION DETERMINAR MAYOR AUSENCIA DEPARTAMENTO
    public String Mayor(){
        String mayor="";
        int temp=0;
            for(int f=0;f<departs;f++){
                for(int c=0;c<mes;c++){
                    if(ausencias[f][c]>temp){
                        mayor= nombre[f+1];
                        temp= ausencias[f][c];
                    }
                }
            }
    return mayor;
    }
```

Así declaro el main

```
//----------------------------------------INICO-------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    //DECLARACION DE VARIABLES
        int ausencias[][];
        String nombre[];
        int regresar=1, opc;
        double prome=0;
        String mayor="";
        
    //OBJETOS DE CLASE
        Scanner datos =new Scanner(System.in);
        AusenciasMes ar = new AusenciasMes();
        ausencias= new int[departs][mes];
        nombre= new String[50];
        
    //ASIGNAR AUSENCIAS DE DEPARTAMENTOS
        for(int f=0;f<departs;f++){
            System.out.println("\nIngrese el nombre del departamento N°"+(f+1));
                datos.next();
                nombre[f]=datos.nextLine();
            for(int c=0;c<mes;c++){
                System.out.println("Ingrese las ausencias en el mes: "+(c+1));
                    ausencias[f][c]= datos.nextInt();
            }
        }
        ar.FijarValor(ausencias, nombre);
```

Y entonces en este Case 2 me está devolviendo un null como respuesta en la impresión, en lugar del nombre.

```
            case 2:
                mayor=ar.Mayor();
                System.out.println("El departamento con más ausencias fue:"+mayor);
```

Agradecería mucho si me ayudaran con esto ^^ !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hace falta que crees otra matriz para copiar la que ya tenías, basta con asignarla directamente. Y los mismo para el arreglo de nombres:

```
private int[][] ausencias;
private String[] nombres;

//--FUNCION FIJAR VALORES
public void fijarValor(int[][] ausencias, String[] nombres){
    this.ausencias = ausencias;
    this.nombres = nombres;
}
```

En el método que busca el mayor lo podrías hacer un poco más genérico recorriendo las filas y columnas según su tamaño y sumando cada campo en una variable aparte que se resetea a 0 cada vez que vas a iniciar la cuenta de ausencias de un departamento nuevo:

```
//--FUNCION DETERMINAR MAYOR AUSENCIA DEPARTAMENTO
public String mayor() {
    String mayor = "";
    int temp = 0;
    for(int f = 0; f < ausencias.length; f++){
        int suma = 0;
        for(int c = 0; c < ausencias[f].length; c++){
            suma += ausencias[f][c];
        }

        if(suma > temp){
            mayor = nombres[f];
            temp = suma;
        }
    }
    return mayor;
}
```

Para imprimir el nombre del departamento con más ausencias:

```
System.out.println("El departamento con más ausencias fue: " + ar.mayor());
```

Algunas sugerencias:

- Por convención los nombres de métodos empiezan en minúscula. Ej: `fijarValor` y `mayor`.
- Ten cuidado con la creación del arreglo de Strings. Si haces esto `String[50]` estarás creando un arreglo de 50 Strings en lugar de un arreglo con tamaño igual a la cantidad de departamentos. Sería más conveniente hacer esto: `String[departs]`.